# YouTube embedded video. paused in each second in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using GSPlayer for playing video in background
screen and I also have to play YouTube video in a view but YouTube video gets amused in each second, if any one can please solve my problem it would be my pleasure,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    let requestURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/B-ZbUAZV8R8?autoplay=1")
    let request = URLRequest(url: requestURL!)
        self.ytWebView.load(request)
    }

func VideoPLayer(url:String,vc:UIViewController,playerView:VideoPlayerView,loop:Bool){
    playerView.isAutoReplay = loop
    playerView.stateDidChanged = { [weak vc] state in
        guard vc != nil else { return }
        
        switch state {
        case .none:
            print("none")
        case .error(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        case .loading:
            print("loading")
        case .paused(let playing, let buffering):
            print("Playing... homeBGVideo")
            self.StateChanged()
        case .playing:
            print("playing")
        }
        switch state {
        case .playing, .paused:
            print("Play")
        default:
            print("Pause")
        }
    }
    playerView.isMuted = true
    playerView.play(for: URL(string: url)!)
    playerView.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 60), using: { [weak vc] _ in
        guard vc != nil else { return }
    })
}
```

Comment: Tell me that ` playerView.isMuted = true
    playerView.play(for: URL(string: url)!)
    playerView.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 60), using: { [weak vc] _ in
        guard vc != nil else { return }
    })`
What does these line of code does?

Comment: actually this is in the functionality that the video must be muted and with this time observer I can handle seekbar of the video but for now I have comment these line but still YouTube player not working,